# WCF discovery slowing processing of callbacks

Tags: wcf, callback, discovery

I have a WCF service that is processing a call, sending that processed data onto another service, and alerting the caller and any other instances of that application by firing a callback.  Originally the callbacks were being called at the end but I found that if the second service was not running that there would be a twenty second delay while we attempted to discover it.  Only then were the callbacks called.  I moved the callback notification before the call to the second service but it still had the delay.  I even tried firing the callbacks on a background process but that didn't work either.  Is there a way to get around this delay, outside of changing the timeout of the discovery?  Here is a code snippet.

```
// Alert the admins of the change.
if (alertPuis)
{
    ReportBoxUpdated(data.SerialNumber);
}

// Now send the change to the box if he's online.
var scope = new Uri(string.Format(@"net.tcp://{0}", data.SerialNumber));
var boxAddress = DiscoveryHelper.DiscoverAddress<IAtcBoxService>(scope);
if (boxAddress != null)
{
    var proxy = GetBoxServiceProxy(boxAddress);

    if (proxy != null)
    {
        proxy.UpdateBox(boxData);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Write("AtcSystemService failed on call to update toool Box: {0}",       
                  data.SerialNumber);
    }
}
else if (mDal.IsBoxDataInPendingUpdates(data.SerialNumber) == false)
            mDal.AddPendingUpdate(data.SerialNumber, null, true, null);
}
```

and

```
private static void ReportBoxUpdated(string serialNumber)
{
    var badCallbacks = new List<string>();

    Action<IAtcSystemServiceCallback> invoke = callback => 
        callback.OnBoxUpdated(serialNumber);
    foreach (var theCallback in AdminCallbacks)
    {
        var callback = theCallback.Value as IAtcSystemServiceCallback;
        try
        {
             invoke(callback);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Log.Write("Failed to execute callback for admin instance {0}: {1}", 
                   theCallback.Key, ex.Message);
             badCallbacks.Add(theCallback.Key);
        }
    }

    foreach (var bad in badCallbacks)  // Clean out any stale callbacks from the list.
    {
        AdminCallbacks.Remove(bad);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered caching the result?